# access struct member using a user variable

Tags: c, struct

Let's asume I have a struct as follows:

```
struct person {
    int age;
    char name[24];
} person;
```

and the user gives an argument which struct member the program should read. `./program age`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    i = person.argv[1];
    printf("%i\n", i);
}
```

this is obviously not possible in this way. Is there a way to read a struct member without typing the exact member name in code?
The only way I could think of is to compare the given string to a string named after each struct member.

Comment: *without typing* Yes! Use an IDE and let IDE do for you! You only need a click to choose the member name...

Comment: No,  you can't. What if someone types it wrong?  You need to check the input for correctness  anyway,  so while you're at it,  you can  type the member name as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to code this, both in terms of typing *and* run-time performance, is probably to use [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/).

Basically, you type the list of names you want, and what you want that to map to (array index, variable pointer, whatever) and it will generate C code to do that for you.

The only problem is that you have to learn how to use it first.

Here's an example from some real-world code:
  [conf.c](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=ccache.git;a=blob;f=conf.c;h=1b1b2b7c70fd046ebf8097cd88f3501cee4c0420;hb=HEAD)
  [confitems.gperf](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=ccache.git;a=blob;f=confitems.gperf;h=ae48d2b4b9724de975eb22fbc03d57182410481e;hb=HEAD)

Note that the gperf file maps a string to a C macro so the programmer can put whatever they like inside that macro, and even use it for different purposes in different places. The C file then includes the generated code, and call the generated function `confitems_get` to do the mapping: string in, macro contents out.

Comment: that looks really powerful. I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 3):

C does not support run-time reflection in any way that would make that easy to get to work. I suspect the best you can do is to write a code-generator that writes the string-to-struct member selection function.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function on the lines

```
char* getTheNameMemberOut(person* p)
{
   int* dodgy = (int*)(void*)(p);
   return (char*)(dodgy + 1); /* use pointer arithmetic to pass over the first member of the structure */
}
```

It heavily relies on you knowing about the layout of the structure.

This could form the basics of some switching you could do to extract various structure members.

Not nice though and hard to maintain. You'll get crashes even after a small change in the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just curious how you can explain this line

```
i = person.argv[1];
```

What does `argv` has to do with your struct to try to access it with `.` ??

Anyways ... you'll have to interpret the arguments you pass to your program and depending on what has been entered display the data you want from your struct. You have to difine a mapping user-input -> data-to-display.

```
argv++; // move to the next pointer, since argv[0] always points to the excutable's name

if(*argv) {
    switch(*argv[0]) {
        case 'a':
            printf("age\n");
        break;
        case 'n':
            printf("name\n");
        break;
        default:
            printf("%c is no valid input\n", *argv[0]);
    }
}
```

If you are refering to [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) then i don't think it is possible in `C`

Comment: I never said my code makes any sense ^^ I just wanted to illustrate what my need is. Your answer is similar to what I was thinking about. And other answers are pointing to the same direction.

Comment: @Hans, I know, and you said it yourself, but i just couldn't resist to ask, sorry. But sometime it is better to explain using pseudo code or prose than using real code, last can be misleading and lets people thinking and guessing "what is he trying to do" or "does he know what he is doing" while first is "I want to do thins and that" :-)

Comment: I got your point and it makes sense. I try to use pseudo code next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some input processing and pointer operations here, I have the following code tested and it works well.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    thePerson.age = 1;
    strcpy(thePerson.name, "John Doe");
    if(argv[1] != NULL){
        int cmp = strcmp(argv[1], "age");
        if (cmp == 0){
            int* pAge = (int*)&thePerson;
            printf("%i\n", *pAge);
        }
        else{
            cmp = strcmp(argv[1], "name");
            if (cmp == 0){
                char* pName = (char*)(&thePerson)+sizeof(int);
                printf("%s\n", pName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hasturkun Yeah I admit that, but since C doesn't support reflection here, we should find a way to solve the problem don't we.